# Anaconda Spyder dies when debugging

Tags: ipython, anaconda, spyder

This happened to me many times.
I was debugging using Spyder.

Sometimes, when I typed in some code in the IPython Console and hit enter, nothing got printed out.
After that, I can still type in codes. However, nothing can be executed.

I tried enter button, exit debug button, run button, etc.
I could only type in codes.

At last, the only thing I could do is restart the kernel.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) This sounds like a bug in Spyder. Please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) and give us there a reproducible example that we can use and test to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your bug report :-)